# godaddy domains, no bids, should I wait for expire?

Tags: domains, godaddy

I'm interested in a godaddy domain name that's on auction.

The domain name has no bids on it. Should I wait for the auction to end and then buy it afterwards or should I bid in the auction?

Basically the question is, will the domain still be available to buy after the auction ends?

Answer (score 1):

GoDaddy and other, similar domain-auction sites look at the traffic arriving at their domains to determine if they're worthwhile members to their portfolio.

If the domain you're interested in is still driving traffic, it may be in their interest to renew the domain before (or shortly after) it expires.  If this is the case, you'll miss out even if no one else has bidded.

How important is the domain to you?  If it's important, I'd be inclined to put in a nominal bid for it.  Of course, if you're talking about more than $100, it might be worth waiting and seeing if they renew.

Only you can decide how important the domain is to you (or your business).

Comment: You should also check how long the domain has *been* registered. It's very, very likely it will not in fact expire at all, just get renewed the second it comes up. Don't think you're going to be able to swoop in and grab it.